# Unable to install anaconda distribution (permission denied)

Tags: linux, bash, permissions

I am trying to install Anaconda on the server machine:

```
LSB Version:    :base-4.0-amd64:base-4.0-noarch:core-4.0-amd64:core- 
4.0-noarch:graphics-4.0-amd64:graphics-4.0-noarch:printing-4.0- 
amd64:printing-4.0-noarch
Distributor ID: RedHatEnterpriseServer
Description:    Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.6 (Santiago)
Release:    6.6
Codename:   Santiago
```

I am not sudo user. I've downloaded installation script `Anaconda3-5.2.0-Linux-x86_64.sh`, change its mod using `chmod u+x Anaconda3-5.2.0-Linux-x86_64.sh` and executed it `bash Anaconda3-5.2.0-Linux-x86_64.sh`.

After the license agreement, folder specification (inside my home directory) I got the following permission denied error:

```
./Anaconda3-5.1.0-Linux-x86_64.sh: line 370: /sonas-hs/engel/hpc/home/mgenkin/anaconda3/pkgs/python-3.6.4-hc3d631a_1/bin/python: Permission denied
```

This is really weird, since I can execute this file by myself from the terminal.

Am I missing something?

Thanks

Edit: I think the problem is that python is already installed.

$ which python

/opt/hpc/pkg/python-2.7/bin/python

Is there a way to remove symbolic link from python?

Comment: The only thing I could recommend is that you need to either become su, or you need to ask the su to run the install for you. Sometimes you may be trying to alter files that you as a normal user don't necessarily have permission to even if you are assigned to admin groups, and this could be the cause of the access denied.

Comment: @RickwhoPrograms hi, thanks for the suggestion. I guess the problem is that some python version is already installed there. I am trying to remove it, see the edit

Comment: be very careful when removing softwares, as they have dependencies that could severely mess up your system!!